# exec and shell_exec not working my lamp server

Tags: php, python, exec, lamp, shell-exec

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["link"]) && !empty($_POST["link"])) {
    $link = $_POST["link"];
    $md5link = md5($link);
    $komut = "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o \"/var/www/html/videos/$md5link.%(ext)s\" $link";
    $cıktı = shell_exec($komut);
    echo $cıktı;


}else{
    echo "Error";


}
?>
```

I bought the server from digitalocean.
This is my php code and output only these

```
[youtube] 6Mgqbai3fKo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 6Mgqbai3fKo: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 6Mgqbai3fKo: Extracting video information
[youtube] 6Mgqbai3fKo: Downloading MPD manifest
```

It doesn't download the video. I also tried with Python

```
def indir(key,url):
    komut = "youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o \"/var/www/html/videos/"+key +r".%(ext)s"+"\" "+url
    os.system(komut)
```

I ran this code with php. If i write php myphpcode.php it runs. But if put in /var/www/html and go website/myphpcode.php with browser it doesn't run.

If I run like this in terminal;

```
/usr/bin/python -c 'import digitaltaraf; print digitaltaraf.indir("a9e17d46c531855434bebb347ea0dddb","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnvShlwsueU")'
or
php mycodefile.php
```

It works, but if i go my website or post to website doesn't download videos. The output looks like the as above.

```
[youtube] mnvShlwsueU: Downloading webpage [youtube] mnvShlwsueU: Downloading video info webpage [youtube] mnvShlwsueU: Extracting video information [youtube] mnvShlwsueU: Downloading MPD manifest
```

Comment: It might not have write permission to that directory.

Comment: What is `%(ext)` supposed to mean in the output filename?

Comment: You should use `escapeshellarg($link)` to prevent command injection.

Comment: %(ext) means .mp3 from music.mp3 or mp4 from video.mp4 in youtube-dl.

Comment: Two likely possibilities: `youtube-dl` isn't in the `PATH` environment variable of the webserver, so use the full path to the executable. Or the webserver userid doesn't have write permission to the directory where you're trying to save the output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I edited the "videos" folder permission (code:777) and it works.

Comment: That's a bad idea. You should change the ownership so it matches the webserver, so only those processes can write to it, not everyone.